# Angular Leaflet Directive simple map example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to get the basic map to show on my page and all I get is a blank page.

This is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="example">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>example</title>
      <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="js/frontend.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="SimpleMapController">
     hello there
     <leaflet></leaflet>
   </body>
  </html>
```

My javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('example', ['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller("SimpleMapController", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        }
    });
}]);
```

This is pretty much exactly as it is explained in the (poorly explained) example. Yet, instead of a map (like in their example), I have a blank screen. On the dev console of the browser I get the following error as well:

```
GET file://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/0/1.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It looks like it's looking for the map pngs on my end when it should be getting them from leaflet. Am I missing something in my html or the js?

Comment: you **MUST** include a `height` and `width` for the leaflet directive.

Comment: Thank you. Why do they not specify that on the angular leaflet directive page? Seems like that's pretty important info.

Comment: they do basically mention it, but it's not really highlighted, https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive#center

Comment: Yeah, I think I saw that it my searching but missed it's importance. They really should put it on their examples page, because as of now it says all you need is <leaflet></leaflet> in the html.

Comment: yeah, the "adding the custom tag `<leaflet>` with some attributes on your HTML code" is kinda vague;  might be worth putting an issue in the GitHub about it....